# Swift: cast to type returned from type(of:)

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm writing a function with this signature:

```
func updateConfigs(key: String, value: Any)
```

Currently, *value* is type `Any`, how do I cast *value* to the type returned from `type(of: value)`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? – Could it be that you need a *generic* function `func updateConfigs<T>(key: String, value: T)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics function like this

```
func updateConfigs<T>(key: String, value: T) -> T {

    return value
}

let result = updateConfigs(key: "test", value: 10.2)
print(type(of: result)) // This will print "Double"
```